# How to use In-App Billing with MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, android, in-app-purchase, xamarin.android, in-app-billing

I am developing an Android application that will need to make use of In-app billing.  I am using Monodroid in Visual Studio and my experience is in C#, I am not very familiar with Java.

My questions are:

1) How do I reference the IMarketBillingService.aidl in Visual Studio? Is it the same as in Eclipse where you have to put it in the src\com\android\vending\billing folder? Also, does it need to be a .aidl file or can I just create a c# interface class for it?

2) Does anyone know of any Android in-app billing tutorials/examples in c#? I have looked at the sample and have read all of the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html).

Not having any experience in Java makes it a little difficult to follow the sample. I have searched everywhere and have not found any documentation on in-app billing with MonoDroid, so any help/links would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT:** One more question: **Is it even possible to use in-app billing with MonoDroid?**

Answer (score 0):

The Android [SDK tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) will generate a proxy class for the remote service exposed by the Android market. If MonoDroid has a similar tool, you need to find out how to use it and generate the necessary files. If not, one way would be to generate one in Java using the standard SDK tools, and then manually port it to C#. If you are not familiar with Java, you should take some time for a crash course. Syntax is not that different from C#, so it should be relatively easy to follow.

Once you have the proxy, you *should* be able to connect to the billing service from C#.

You might get better answers on official MonoDroid forums, mailing lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to translate that library into C#:

https://github.com/jmawebtech/MonoGame-StarterKits/tree/master/Android/InAppBilling

Feel free to check in code or provide suggestions.